# Neo4j official javascript driver with electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, driver, electron

I was trying to create a sample demo app for Neo4j using electron and the Neo4j official npm packaged driver, and my code is really really basic but I'm getting an error once I try to open a session. This code is written in the index.html in a script tag:

```
require('./renderer.js')
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));

var session = driver.session();
```

upon the last call this is the error message i get in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Don't know how to send buffer: NodeBuffer( position=0 )60 60 b0 17 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Has anyone ever encountered a problem like this?

Answer (score 1):

I have created an application using electron and Vuejs, very simple it runs a simple cypher query and print to the browser.

First thing, you have to require the script as a web browser resource :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/neo4j-web.js"></script>
```

this will change in the future, neo4j is aware of this

Secondly, this resource needs to be in your assets or you can use the neo4j cdn

Then I was able to use neo4j with a global import :

```
var driver = global.neo4j.v1.driver('bolt://localhost')
        var session = driver.session()
        session.run('CREATE (n:Electron) RETURN n')
          .subscribe({
            onNext: function (record) {
              console.log(record._fields)
            },
            onCompleted: function () {
              session.close()
            },
            onError: function (error) {
              console.log(error)
            }
          })
```

Third thing you'll need to allow the neo4j externals in your webpack config :

```
externals: {
  'neo4j': 'neo4j'
  }
```

You can see my repo here : https://github.com/ikwattro/electron-vue-test

As I said, it is very a hello world but working.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem seems to be that the driver detects that it's running in the browser and tries to use the websocket channel.

You can "force" the driver to use the node channel by changing this:

```
var Channel = undefined;
if (_chWebsocket2["default"].available) {
  Channel = _chWebsocket2["default"].channel;
} else if (_chNode2["default"].available) {
  Channel = _chNode2["default"].channel;
} else {
  throw (0, _error.newError)("Fatal: No compatible transport available. Need to run on a platform with the WebSocket API.");
}
```

to

```
var Channel = undefined;
Channel = _chNode.channel;
```

at this file:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/blob/1.1/lib/v1/internal/connector.js#L64